# Need to combine 2 queries to report yearly and quarterly results of a sales analysis

Tags: sql, sapb1

I am writing a query for a customer that will show yearly ar invoice information, and quarterly ar invoice information ( including gross profit / gross profit % ) in the same report result.

Here is the current query I have created

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate  DateTime
/* SELECT FROM [dbo].[OINV] T0 WHERE */ SET  @StartDate   = /* 
T0.DocDate*/ '[%0]'
/* SELECT FROM [dbo].[OINV] T0 WHERE */ SET  @EndDate = /* T0.DocDate*/ 
'[%1]'
SELECT T3.GroupName,

(SELECT COUNT(DocNum) 
FROM OINV WHERE 
(DocDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND GroupName = T3.GroupName) 
[A/R Invoices], 

SUM(T1.LineTotal) [Total A/R Invoice], 
SUM(T1.GrssProfit) [Gross Profit], 
SUM(((T1.GrssProfit/T1.LineTotal)*100))/(SELECT COUNT(DocNum) 

FROM OINV 

WHERE (DocDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND GroupName = 
T3.GroupName) [Gross Profit %]



FROM [dbo].[OINV] T0 INNER JOIN [dbo].[INV1] T1 ON T0.DocEntry = 
T1.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OCRD] T2 ON T2.CardCode = T0.CardCode
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OCRG] T3  ON  T3.GroupCode = T2.GroupCode  
WHERE T0.DocDate BETWEEN  @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY T3.GroupName
```

It returns 
Customer Group, Total invoices, Total invoice value, gross profit, and gross profit % for the date parameters selected

In my example, I have ran it for dates 1/1/2006 and 12/31/2006

```
GroupName   A/R Invoices    Total A/R Invoice   Gross Profit    Gross Profit %  
Large Accounts  9   32,075.00   10,709.46   36.17   
Distributors    9   17,350.00   4,512.92    20.28   
High Tech       9   16,950.00   6,347.04    24.44   
Construction    9   20,100.00   8,061.80    31.35
```

Whenever I run it for the dates 1/1/2006 and 3/3/2006 it returns the correct quarterly amount.

I need to combine the 2 so that it returns a yearly total and quarterly total in the same query

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Below is updated with the results of the query you provided

[query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNcxx.png)

It is bringing in the data per month.

Final Result

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate  DateTime
/* SELECT FROM [dbo].[OINV] T0 WHERE */ SET  @StartDate   = /* 
T0.DocDate*/ '[%0]'
/* SELECT FROM [dbo].[OINV] T0 WHERE */ SET  @EndDate = /* T0.DocDate*/ 
'[%1]'
Select T3.GroupName,  dateadd(quarter, datediff(quarter, 0, T0.DocDate),0) 
as 'Quarter Start Date',

(SELECT COUNT(DocNum) 
FROM OINV WHERE 
(DocDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND GroupName = T3.GroupName) 
[A/R Invoices], 

SUM(T1.LineTotal) [Total A/R Invoice], 
SUM(T1.GrssProfit) [Gross Profit], 
SUM(((T1.GrssProfit/T1.LineTotal)*100))/(SELECT COUNT(DocNum) 

FROM OINV 

WHERE (DocDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND GroupName = 
T3.GroupName) [Gross Profit %]

FROM [dbo].[OINV] T0 INNER JOIN [dbo].[INV1] T1 ON T0.DocEntry = 
T1.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OCRD] T2 ON T2.CardCode = T0.CardCode
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OCRG] T3  ON  T3.GroupCode = T2.GroupCode  
WHERE T0.DocDate BETWEEN  @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY T3.GroupName, dateadd(quarter, datediff(quarter, 0, 
T0.DocDate),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get Quarter`with`group by`

```
SELECT T3.GroupName, SUBSTRING((CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),T3.DOCDATE,106)),4,11) Q,

(SELECT COUNT(DocNum) 
FROM OINV WHERE 
(DocDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND GroupName = T3.GroupName) 
[A/R Invoices], 

SUM(T1.LineTotal) [Total A/R Invoice], 
SUM(T1.GrssProfit) [Gross Profit], 
SUM(((T1.GrssProfit/T1.LineTotal)*100))/(SELECT COUNT(DocNum) 

FROM OINV 

WHERE (DocDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND GroupName = 
T3.GroupName) [Gross Profit %]

FROM [dbo].[OINV] T0 INNER JOIN [dbo].[INV1] T1 ON T0.DocEntry = 
T1.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OCRD] T2 ON T2.CardCode = T0.CardCode
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OCRG] T3  ON  T3.GroupCode = T2.GroupCode  
WHERE T0.DocDate BETWEEN  @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY T3.GroupName, SUBSTRING((CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),T3.DOCDATE,106)),4,11)
```

your date input would be

```
1/1/2006 and 12/31/2006
```

Comment: Hi Simonare, thank you for your response. Here is the result of the query after I run it        1). [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'Quarter' is not a recognized built-in function name.
2). [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@StartDate".
3). [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for S

Comment: I thought you are using mysql sorry. check my update

Comment: No worries, thank you SO MUCH for the help, I really appreciate it. I am still having issues combining the totals in to Quarters. the results return the results for the specific month. I am trying to get a yearly total from 1/1 - 12/31 as well as quarterly values in the same report (1/1-3/30 Q1, 4/1-6/30 Q2, etc)

Comment: can you update your question with relevant results which my query is giving you and point out the problem on it? because the query I shared with you needs to give you quarters right now

Comment: Hello, I have figured it out using a datepart function I will update above

Comment: If you believe that this answer is usefull and give you an insight about your problem, please consider to upvote it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate  DateTime
/* SELECT FROM [dbo].[OINV] T0 WHERE */ SET  @StartDate   = /* 
T0.DocDate*/ '[%0]'
/* SELECT FROM [dbo].[OINV] T0 WHERE */ SET  @EndDate = /* T0.DocDate*/ 
'[%1]'
Select T3.GroupName,  dateadd(quarter, datediff(quarter, 0, T0.DocDate),0) 
as 'Quarter Start Date',

(SELECT COUNT(DocNum) 
FROM OINV WHERE 
(DocDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND GroupName = T3.GroupName) 
[A/R Invoices], 

SUM(T1.LineTotal) [Total A/R Invoice], 
SUM(T1.GrssProfit) [Gross Profit], 
SUM(((T1.GrssProfit/T1.LineTotal)*100))/(SELECT COUNT(DocNum) 

FROM OINV 

WHERE (DocDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND GroupName = 
T3.GroupName) [Gross Profit %]

FROM [dbo].[OINV] T0 INNER JOIN [dbo].[INV1] T1 ON T0.DocEntry = 
T1.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OCRD] T2 ON T2.CardCode = T0.CardCode
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OCRG] T3  ON  T3.GroupCode = T2.GroupCode  
WHERE T0.DocDate BETWEEN  @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY T3.GroupName, dateadd(quarter, datediff(quarter, 0, 
T0.DocDate),0)
```